# How can i change android button color inside my java class?

Tags: java, android

I tried something like this

```
package com.example.memorygameproject;

import android.os.Bundle;

    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat;
    
    import com.example.memorygameproject.databinding.ActivityGameBinding;
    
    public class ActivityGame extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private ActivityGameBinding bind;
    
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    
           bind.button1.setBackgroundColor(bind.button1.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        }
    }
```

But for some reason my app crashes.I've also tried this

```
bind.button1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

But the app crashed again.It appearently throws a null pointer exception but i can't see why.How to fix this?

Comment: `bind` is null, because you're not calling `this.bind = ActivityGameBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater())` and `setContentView(bind.getRoot())`. You also likely want to _tint_ the button instead of setting its background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instaed of

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
```

your code must be

```
bind = ActivityGameBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
setContentView(bind.getRoot());
```

Comment: That solved it.Thanks a lot.But i don't get it.I used databinding before and didn't have to do something like that.I was just able to use components with the Binding class referance.so what is the diffrence here?

Comment: The difference is that this is for view control, you can read more about it at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding